# Date query with Hibernate on Timestamp Column in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, orm, date

A table has timestamp column. A sample value in that could be 2010-03-30 13:42:42. With Hibernate, I am doing a range query Restrictions.between("column-name", fromDate, toDate).

The Hibernate mapping for this column is as follows.

```
<property name="orderTimestamp"  column="order_timestamp" type="java.util.Date" />
```

Let's say, I want to find out all the records that have the date 30th March 2010 and 31st March 2010. A range query on this field is done as follows.

```
Date fromDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2010-03-30");
Date toDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2008-03-31");
Expression.between("orderTimestamp", fromDate, toDate);
```

This doesn't work.

The query is converted to respective timestamps as "2010-03-30 00:00:00" and "2010-03-31 00:00:00". So, all the records for the 31st March 2010 are ignored.

A simple solution to this problem could be to have the end date as "2010-03-31 23:59:59." But, I would like to know if there is way to match only the date part of the timestamp column.

Also, is `Expression.between()` inclusive of both limits? Documentation doesn't throw any light on this.

Comment: I believe between is always exclusive on both limits. Why don't you just remove 1 millisecond and add 1 millisecond to each of them?

Comment: @jishi it's database dependent (and most of time inclusive I believe).

Comment: Shashikant could you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

> , I would like to know if there is way to match only the date part of the timestamp column.

If you don't want a TIMESTAMP, use a DATE (and shouldn't you use `type="date"`?).

> Also, is Expression.between() inclusive of both limits?

It seems that the behavior of the SQL BETWEEN operator is [database dependent](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp). With PosgresQL, the BETWEEN expression:

```
x BETWEEN y AND z
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
y <= x AND x <= z
```

i.e. inclusive.

Comment: type="date" doesn't help. Want to try your earlier idea of annotation, but unfortunately, I'm on Hibernate version older than 3.3 in which annotations were introduced.

Comment: @Shashikant I posted my answer a bit too fast, didn't realize you were using xml mappings (hence the update). But indeed, Hibernate annotations has a @Temporal annotation for this (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e342). There must be some kind of equivalent with xml... Do you have control on your physical model BTW?

Comment: Except DB schema (ie timstamp column) and Hibernate version, I can change everthing else. Temporal annotation sounds useful but as I mentioned, I can't move to Hibernate 3.3+. 

Also, if I add Temporal annoation as Date, while retrieving the row, will it truncate timestamp to date? If yes, that is undesirable.

Thanks for the help, Pascal. Modding +1.

Comment: @PascalThivent using Temporal annotation as date skips the gson serialization on api request and hence getting previous date on client side.That if dob on database is '13-11-1987' then getting it as '12-11-1987' as rest api response.

Comment: @PascalThivent See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58688079/add-temporal-annoation-as-date-skips-gson-serialization-on-rest-api-request

Answer (score 1):

The "2010-03-31 23:59:59." border condition is potentially dangerous: if there was a transaction in the system between 23:59:59 and 00:00:00, you'd miss it. If you have enough transactions daily and a long enough period, a report is going to break and you'll spend hours to find out why.

PostgreSQL `between` [includes the limits](http://www.java2s.com/Code/PostgreSQL/Select-Query/UsingBETWEEN.htm) so it would not even be safe to set the end date to 2010-04-01 00:00:00. Use lt() and gt() to be sure.

Comment: still that wouldn't fly, that will include 2010-04-01 00:00 AM

Comment: Using lt("endDate", endDate) where endDate = "2010-04-01 00:00" would include records with end date 2010-04-01 00:00? I don't think that is the case.

Comment: Thanks for link for 'between' being inclusive for PostgreSQL. 

Boundary conditions is not much of a worry as timestamps are recorded only to the precision of seconds. To use, less-than or greater-than, I need to use less-than("2010-04-01 00:00:00") and greater-than-or-equal-to("2010-03-30 00:00:00")

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can CAST orderTimestamp to a DATE. HQL [does have support](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use cast(your_data, date), remember the second arg of the cast function must be lower, or it wont work.

Att.: Samuel\Maycon