# Add Temporal annoation as Date skips Gson Serialization on Rest api Request

Tags: java, json, date, gson, temporal

In my java application i was using REST API that returned data in JSON format, and noticed that this particular API formatted it's dates in a peculiar way: "Nov 1, 2019" , But problem is that the actual date on the server is "2019-11-02".That means I am getiing date minimized to previous date.I have added gson serialization for both Date and Timestamp values using UTC timezone format, but what i noted is the Date values skip the serialization part on the code and only Timestamp values are using the serialization.I have used @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) for date values that why it skips the date serialization.My server is on another country.Below is the complete json that i got after formatting.

```
jsonAccts [{"id":8,"userId":2,"departmentId":45,"effectiveFrom":"Jun 9, 2019","endsOn":"Nov 1, 2019","createdBy":2,"createdOn":"2019-11-02 05:34:11"}]
```

Below is the code that i used for gson formatting.

```
Gson gson;
GsonBuilder builder;
SimpleDateFormat dtf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat dtfDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
String jsonAccts = null;
try{
    builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new JsonSerializer<Timestamp>() {
        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(Timestamp src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            dtf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            String jsDate = dtf.format(src);
            return new JsonPrimitive(jsDate);
        }
    });
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonSerializer<Date>() {
        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            dtf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            String jsDate = dtf.format(src);
            return new JsonPrimitive(jsDate);
        }
    });
    gson = builder.create();
    List<ClassTeacher> allActPgmMap = new ArrayList<ClassTeacher>();
    allActPgmMap = springDao.getClassTeacherList(Integer.parseInt(deptId));
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ClassTeacher>>() {}.getType();
    jsonAccts = gson.toJson(allActPgmMap, listType);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return jsonAccts;
```

Here the `builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonSerializer<Date>() {}` is been not used for `effectiveFrom` and `endsOn` on api request.
Below is the ClassTeacher class.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.sql.Timestamp;
    import java.util.Date;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "class_teacher")
    public class ClassTeacher implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private long userId;

        @Column(name = "department_id")
        private long departmentId;

        @Column(name = "effective_from")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)     
        private Date effectiveFrom;

        @Column(name = "ends_on")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)     
        private Date endsOn;

        @Column(name="created_by")
        private long createdBy;

        @Column(name="created_on")
        private Timestamp createdOn;

        public ClassTeacher() {

        }

        public ClassTeacher(long id, long departmentId, long userId, Date effectiveFrom, Date endsOn, long createdBy, Timestamp createdOn) {
            this.id = id;
            this.departmentId = departmentId;
            this.userId = userId;
            this.effectiveFrom = effectiveFrom;
            this.endsOn = endsOn;
            this.createdBy = createdBy;
            this.createdOn = createdOn;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public long getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(long userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public long getDepartmentId() {
            return departmentId;
        }

        public void setDepartmentId(long departmentId) {
            this.departmentId = departmentId;
        }

        public Date getEffectiveFrom() {
            return effectiveFrom;
        }

        public void setEffectiveFrom(Date effectiveFrom) {
            this.effectiveFrom = effectiveFrom;
        }

        public Date getEndsOn() {
            return endsOn;
        }

        public void setEndsOn(Date endsOn) {
            this.endsOn = endsOn;
        }

        public long getCreatedBy() {
            return createdBy;
        }

        public void setCreatedBy(long createdBy) {
            this.createdBy = createdBy;
        }

        public Timestamp getCreatedOn() {
            return createdOn;
        }

        public void setCreatedOn(Timestamp createdOn) {
            this.createdOn = createdOn;
        }
    }
```

Here the `createdOn` is using the `builder.registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new JsonSerializer<Timestamp>() {}`,but `effectiveFrom` and `endsOn` are not using the serializer.I have used `'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'` here for gson.

Comment: hope at here `builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonSerializer<Date>() {` date is `java.util.Date` class

Comment: @dkb yes, its java.util.Date

Comment: works fine for me, exclude data fetched from DB so creating Object manually, Ref: https://gist.github.com/dineshbhagat/f7620e21ce2e7a26093e4a4ef92ef391

Comment: @dkb pls add a System.out.println("....") inside builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonSerializer<Date>() {} and check whether its printing??

Comment: @dkb no problem with fetching the data from database and returning it to  client, only problem is the date serializer is not working bcos of the date format from query result.

Comment: If you would have checked gist, I have added output as well, though added System.out too, and works fine

Comment: @dkb Sorry,the Hql query returned date as java.sql.Date, is that the reason why its skips the serialization??

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use for example `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

If you use **`@Temporal`** annotation, then your Date object may be instance of one of the following classes, depending on the TemporalType enum you provide:

1. **DATE** (`java.sql.Date`)
2. **TIME** (`java.sql.Time`)
3. **TIMESTAMP** (`java.sql.Timestamp`)

So, if you are using **@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)**, you have to `registerTypeAdapter` on `java.sql.Date` class

```
builder.registerTypeAdapter(java.sql.Date.class, new JsonSerializer.....);
```

Comment: This is 2024 after all. You should a long time ago have stopped using `Date`, `Time` and `Timestamp`, Those classes had severe design problems and have been outdated the last 10 years. Use `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` and either `OffsetDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`. All are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).